# Twilio Video using Webrtc

Tags: webrtc, twilio, twilio-api

According to Twilio, all I see is information about STUN/TURN and how they charge money for using the TURN/relay server. However, it doesn't make sense to do P2P (wrt performance) for a multi-party conferencing.

So, i'm curious to know if Twilio uses some kind of a media server (for MCU/SFU) in between or does it do P2P connections.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. If you want to know how a third party site or vendor is doing something, contact them directly.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Video API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started) is a room based API, users join rooms to connect to other users. There are two types of rooms though.

**Peer to peer rooms** use WebRTC's peer to peer nature to connect, and we don't recommend that you try to connect more than 4 users in this way.

**Group rooms** use a server-routed topology to support a larger number of Participants and features like Recording.

You can set the default room type in the Twilio console on the [Video room settings](https://www.twilio.com/console/video/configure) page. You can also [create rooms using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#post-list-resource) and set the type at the time of creation.

Let me know if that helps.